# Automatic listing of authors in a document

Tags: macros, comma-separated-list, token-lists

I have a command `\by{ }` that lets me list authors of an article like this:

```
\by{
{author 1}{tagline} \\
{author 2}{tagline} \\
{author 3}{tagline} \\
<etc.>
}
```

[image]

I would like to store `author 1`, `author 2`, `author 3`, etc. in some sort of list and print that list like this:

```
author 1 \\
author 2 \\
author 3 \\
<etc.>
```

I also want to be able to add names manually (i.e. names that are not used in `\by`). An exaple of this is the name `Jane` in the MWE.

One important thing is that each name only appears *once* in the list. If `author 1` has written two articles, their name should still only appear once in the printed list of authors.

I also have an environment `\mytextbox` for displaying this list. However, **I do not want to modify this environment to automaticually print authors**, because I still want to be able to manually input authors in this environment as a "failsafe" if, for some reason, there should be an error with the automatic list (for example because of a new imported package in the future or another new pice of code). I chose to include this environment in the MWE to ensure that solutions will be compatible with it.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,paper=a4,openany,parskip=half,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{DejaVuSans} % Sans-serif
\usepackage{lipsum}


% mytextbox environment:
\RequirePackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand{\overlaytextbox}[3]{% \placetextbox{<horizontal pos>}{<vertical pos>}{<stuff>}
        \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{#1\paperwidth},%
        \LenToUnit{#2\paperheight}){\vtop{{\null}\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{#3}}}
  }%
}%
\newcommand{\mytextbox}[2][black]{%
    \overlaytextbox{0.05}{0.94}{% 0.65 og 0.94 for plassering til høyre
        \color{#1}
        \subsubsection*{Authors}%
        %\vspace{3mm}%
        \linespread{1.6}\selectfont
            {\itshape
            #2
            }%
    }%
}%

% \by command:
\def\by#1{\vspace{1mm}{\centering\fontsize{7}{10}\sffamily Written by \\}\vspace{5pt}\setbox1=\box0 \setbox1=\box3 \byA\\#1\end}
\def\byA#1{\ifx\end#1\expandafter\byC
   \else
   \expandafter\byB
   \fi
}
\def\byB#1#2{%
   \ifvoid3
      \setbox1=\hbox{\makebox{\vtop{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr{\fontsize{9}{11}\sffamily\MakeUppercase{#1}}\vspace{-5pt}\cr{\fontsize{7}{10}\sffamily#2}\cr}}}}%
      \ifvoid0\setbox0=\box1
      \else
         \setbox2=\hbox{\unhcopy0 \ \hspace{2mm}{\fontsize{7}{10}\sffamily and} \hspace{2mm} \unhcopy1 \ \hspace{2mm} {\fontsize{7}{10}\sffamily et al.}}
         \ifdim\wd2>\hsize 
            \setbox3=\hbox{ \unhbox0 \ \hspace{2mm}{\fontsize{7}{10}\sffamily et al.}\hspace{2mm}}
         \else
            \setbox0=\hbox{\unhbox0 \ \hspace{2mm}{\fontsize{7}{10}\sffamily and}\hspace{2mm} \unhbox1}
         \fi
      \fi
   \fi
   \byA
}
\def\byC{\ifvoid3 \setbox3=\box0 \fi \hbox to\hsize{\hss\box3\hss}\bigskip}

\begin{document}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{center}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\mytextbox[red]{
% some command to list authors here:
% for exaple \authorlist
Someone \\
Firstname Lastname \\
Myname is Bond \\
Paul \\
Jane \\
}
\clearpage

{\centering \sffamily\textbf{First Article}\\}
\by{
  {Someone}{Tagline}
}

\lipsum[1]

{\centering \sffamily\textbf{Second Article}\\}
\by{
{Firstname Lastname}{Hey ho matey yo ho} \\
{Someone}{New tagline}\\
{Myname is Bond}{Secret Service} \\
{Paul}{Physicist}
}

\lipsum[1]

{\centering \sffamily\textbf{Third Article}\\}
\by{
{Paul}{Still a physicist}
}

\lipsum[1]

{\centering \sffamily\textbf{Poem}\\}

\begin{center}
    foo \\
    baz \\
    baa foo!
\end{center}

Thank you Jane for creating this poem!

\end{document}
```

How can I do this? Where can I find more information on how to make lists like this in LaTeX? I guess I have to have some sort of if case to check if the author already is on the list?

The only solution I can currently think of would be an `expl3` token list and `\str_case:nnF{ author }{ {<compare to list element>}{} }{ <add to list> }`. However, I think it may not be a good idea to combine `expl3` and plain TeX. Also, I'm not entierly sure on how to implement this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `\addauthor{#1}` into the `\byB` macro (on the top of this macro):

```
\def\byB#1#2{%
   \addauthor{#1}%
   \ifvoid3
   ...
```

and you can define the macro `\addauthor`:

```
\def\authorlist{}
\def\addauthor#1{\immediate\write\csname @mainaux\endcsname{\string\xauthor{#1}}}
\def\xauthor#1{%
   \unless \ifcsname xa:#1\endcsname
      \expandafter\gdef\csname xa:#1\endcsname{}
      \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\authorlist\expandafter{\authorlist #1\\}
   \fi
}
```

Finally, you can use `\authorlist` in your red box because this list includes

```
author1\\author2\\author3\\...
```

after the second run of TeX. We used the `.aux` file because you want to know `\authorlist` before authors are read by `\by`.

If you want to add Jane to the list, you can do this manually in your red box or you can write `\addauthor{Jane}` after the "foo baz baa foo" poem in the "Thanks" text.